toggle the bits and return the unsigned 32 bit integer of same. Not All test cases running
I am solving a 'hackerRank' coding challenge (basic) using JavaScript. the problem is,
You will be given a list of 32 bit unsigned integers. Flip all the bits (1->0 and 0->1) and return the result as an unsigned integer.
here is my code (I aware that i tried a cumbersome  way and there is a very easy single line to code as well return (~n >>> 0)


function flippingBits(n) {
  function dtb(num){
    let rem = 0 ;
    let i = 0;
    let op = 0;

    while(num !== 0){
      rem = num % 2;
      op = op + (rem*(Math.pow(10,i)));
      i++;
      num = (num - rem) / 2;
    }
    let out = String(op).padStart(32,'0');
    return out;
  }

  function toggle(n){
    let newOp = dtb(n);
    let finalOp = '';
    for(let i=0;i<newOp.length;i++){
      if(newOp[i] === '1'){
        finalOp += '0';
      } else {
        finalOp += '1';
      }
    }
    return finalOp;
  }

  function btd(n){
    let num = toggle(n);
    let op = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<num.length;i++){
      op = op + (Math.pow(2,(num.length- 1)-i)*num[i]);
    }
    return op;
  }

  return btd(n);
}



/* 
Input (stdin) 3 0 802743475 35601423

my Output (stdout) 4294967295 4292350879 4293886735

Expected Output 4294967295 3492223820 4259365872
*/

const legit = (n) => (~n >>> 0);

let input = [3,0,802743475,35601423];

input.forEach((n) => {
  let mine = flippingBits(n);
  let theirs = legit(n);
  console.log(`mine ${mine}, theirs ${theirs}`);
  console.assert(mine === theirs);
});



the inputs that passed
enter image description here
the inputs that failed
Input (stdin)
3
0
802743475
35601423
my Output (stdout)
4294967295
4292350879
4293886735
Expected Output
4294967295
3492223820
4259365872

If you don’t want to use bit twiddling then making use of num.toString(2) and parseInt(binaryString, 2) would make converting between the two much simpler.

great i will surely give it a try, but im looking a deep dived solution for it so that i can understand where im going wrong in my code and get a clarity in bit manipulation

Sometimes the numbers you create in dtb (in the op variable) are larger than the maximum safe integer.  Not only that, but they are expressed in scientific notation when you call String(op).  You do not need to construct such a huge number to do the conversion (see above functions I mentioned).

Or you could make op a string instead.
